# Set up Jenkins-BlueOcean for non-trivial C++ project with dependencies

Tags: c++, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to setup pipeline (-s) for the project, which is a little more complicated than `./configure && make && make install`. Thus, unfortunately for me, I find all the tutorials in this universe on this topic useless, as they demo simplest unrealistic "hello-world" examples which are intuitive to configure using Pipeline even without a tutorial.

I'd like to hear opinions from experienced folks, whether I can use Jenkins+BlueOcean tor [the library](https://github.com/remap/ndnrtc/blob/master/cpp/INSTALL.md) (link to full build instructions -- a set of shell commands) I'm working on. Here are the specifics and requirements of the project:

- it has dependencies: some can be installed using package managers (`brew`, `apt-get`), some should be compiled from source (WebRTC, OpenFEC, ndn-cpp);
- it builds for 3 platforms (macOS, Linux and Android), for each platform, there are subtleties in build steps for the dependencies, but generally, the steps are similar;
- I need to save artifacts for compiled dependencies so that they can be re-used for future faster builds (on the development branch) as well as distributed to the public;
- the following automatic builds need to be maintained:

  - nightly-master,
  - nightly-dev,
  - release-master (when new version tag added in the master branch),
  - change-master (new commit/merge in master),
  - change-dev (new commit in development branch),
  - change-dependency (when any of dependencies' source code changes).

Please, I'd appreciate any opinion on whether it's possible with Jenkins+BlueOcean and how shall I start on that. Thanks.

As the beginning -- I currently set up Jenkins with 3 nodes (macOS 10.13, macOS 10.14, Ubuntu 14.04) labeled `macOS` and `linux`. I however, do not understand how should I tell pipeline to stick to one node and do things a slightly differently for different platforms.

Comment: *Try*. When you get stuck on something *specific* then ask a single specific question about the bit you got stuck on. As is, this is too broad.

Comment: It is not broad - there is a specific set of instructions how to build the project.

Comment: Your project still doesn’t seem to be very complicated. I‘ll be easy to realize this is Jenkins. As Blue Ocean is just a different kind of UI it Dir not really matter for the question where you’ll be able to realize your builds with Jenkins or not. As long as you only have to deal with calling shell commands and archiving artifacts you’ll be pretty fine using the snippet generator for Jenkins Pipeline jobs.